# Show that the equation of the folium of Descartes in terms of $x$ and $y$ is $x^3+y^3=axy$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations, parametric

I'm given that the parametric equations are

$x=\frac{at}{1+t^3}$ and $y=\frac{at^2}{1+t^3}$ and that $a>0$

Here's my attempt at a solution:

Find $x^3$ and $y^3$ in terms of $t$..

$x^3=\left(\frac{at}{1+t^3}\right)^3$ and $y^3=\left(\frac{at^2}{1+t^3}\right)^3$

Add them together:

$x^3+y^3=\left(\frac{at}{1+t^3}\right)^3+\left(\frac{at^2}{1+t^3}\right)^3$

Since we're trying to prove that the above is equal to $axy$, we find $axy$ in terms of $t$ which is:

$axy=a\left(\frac{at}{1+t^3}\right)\left(\frac{at^2}{1+t^3}\right)$

Then finally to prove $x^3+y^3=axy$ I have to prove:

$a\left(\frac{at}{1+t^3}\right)\left(\frac{at^2}{1+t^3}\right) = \left(\frac{at}{1+t^3}\right)^3+\left(\frac{at^2}{1+t^3}\right)^3$

And that's where I'm stuck.  I can't figure out why those two things are equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In
$$a\left(\frac{at}{1+t^3}\right)\left(\frac{at^2}{1+t^3}\right) = \left(\frac{at}{1+t^3}\right)^3+\left(\frac{at^2}{1+t^3}\right)^3,$$
the left side is
$a\left(\dfrac{at}{1+t^3}\right)\left(\dfrac{at^2}{1+t^3}\right)
=\dfrac{a^3t^3}{(1+t^3)^2}
$
and the right side is

$\begin{align}
\left(\frac{at}{1+t^3}\right)^3+\left(\frac{at^2}{1+t^3}\right)^3
&=\frac{a^3t^3}{(1+t^3)^3}+\frac{a^3t^6}{(1+t^3)^3}\\
&=\frac{a^3t^3+a^3t^6}{(1+t^3)^3}\\
&=\frac{a^3t^3(1+t^3)}{(1+t^3)^3}\\
&=\frac{a^3t^3}{(1+t^3)^2}\\
\end{align}
$

so the two are equal.

Answer (score 1):

Find t first by dividing the 1st equation by the second equation (note that $1+t^3$ will cancel each other):

$x/y = at/at^2$

$x/y = 1/t$

$t = y/x.$

Now, substitute this to the 1st equation, simplify and you will be done :)

Comment: This is the exact same approach as what I'm doing, but instead of putting everything in terms of $t$ you're putting it in terms of $x$ and $y$.  The "simplify and you will be done" part is what I am having trouble with.

Comment: it should be easy with this approach. after this, you get $x=a(y/x)/(1+(y/x)^3)$, divide the numerator and denominator by $x^3$, you get $x=ax^2y/(x^3+y^3)$, then finally, $x^3+y^3=axy$.